# How to simulate keys input in DOS command / C# (GPG)

Tags: .net-4.0, batch-file, process, gnupg

I'm executing GPG as DOS commands in C#. Works in majority.
I've managed reading passwords from standard input (similarly to written [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4069919/command-line-gpg-decrypting-using-c-passphrase))

But I've stuck on **keys deletion** what you need is execute below command:

```
gpg --delete-key "Key Name"
```

But problem is GPG asks you if you are sure you want to delete this key and what you
need is **press Y < ENTER >** what I'm not able to archive...
Seems it doesn't read from StdIO

I've tried DOS-like solution

```
echo Y | gpg --delete-key "Key Name"
```

or making txt file with Y as 1st line and < Enter > as 2nd

```
type yes.txt | gpg --delete-key "Key Name"
```

Both didnt work...

Any idea how to make it working ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to pass `--yes` as a param.

From the [GPG manual](http://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg-devel/Operational-GPG-Commands.html#index-delete_002dkey-144):

> `--delete-key name`
>
> Remove key from the public keyring. In batch mode either `--yes` is required or the key must be specified by fingerprint. This is a safeguard against accidental deletion of multiple keys.

Comment: sounds good but doesnt work to me. I've tried gpg --delete-key "abc" --yes.  Is that working to you ?

Comment: OKAY found it: shall be done as follow: gpg --batch --yes --delete-key "abc". Thanks

Comment: `--batch`  Use batch mode. Never ask, do not allow interactive commands.  

`--yes`  

Assume "yes" on most questions.